# Reading csv file in R markdown, having trouble with separating the variables of dataset

Tags: r, csv, r-markdown

I have a csv file that contains 6 variables of diamonds

````
```{r}
diamonds <- read.csv2("diamonds.csv")
```
````

when I tried to read the variables, I used

````
```{r}
names(diamonds) 
```
````

but I got the output:

[1] "Price.Carat.Size.Color.Clarity.Cut"

instead of something like:

[6] "Price"       "Carat"  "Size" "Color"  "Clarity"    "Cut"

How do I modify my code or perhaps my csv file to adjust this right?

Comment: I wonder if you read the `csv` file correctly. What is the output of `str(diamonds)` if you run it right after `diamonds <- read.csv2("diamonds.csv")`?

Comment: 'data.frame': 2690 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Price.Carat.Size.Color.Clarity.Cut: Factor w/ 2379 levels "1000\t0.3\tE\tVVS1\tExcellent",..: 1 5 2 8 6 4 3 7 18 14 ...

Comment: That's the output

Comment: There you have your answer why `names(diamonds)` didn't give you what you wanted

Comment: you can copy and paste part of your csv file on https://pastebin.com/ then share the link here